# R: How to get even spacing between these data points and adjust photos

Tags: r

I am trying to evenly space out these "lollipop" data points. Essentially, I don't want the y aesthetic effecting the y position of the data. I'd also like to adjust the headshots so they are not behind the point.

```
#library(devtools)
#devtools::install_github("camdenk/mlbplotR")
#library(ggplot2)
Top10 %>%
ggplot(aes(x=xba.x, y=xba.y)) +
mlbplotR::geom_mlb_headshots(aes(player_id = 
player_id), height = 0.15)+
geom_point(colour = "black") + 
geom_segment( aes(x=xba.y, xend=xba.x, y=xba.y, 
yend= xba.y))+
geom_point(aes(x=xba.x, y=xba.y))+
geom_point(aes(x=xba.y, y=xba.y))
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want `xba.y` to determine the `y` position then don't use it. To get even spacing you could just use a sequence of integers e.g. `1:10`. For the photos, try adding `x = xba.x + 0.007` inside `aes()` to nudge them over.

Comment: Also you don't need to keep repeating the `y = xba.y` aesthetic. Once specified in `ggplot()` the rest of the plot inherits it by default.

Comment: And the last two `geom_point` just overplot on the first. Try removing them and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Without your exact data I can't verify this solution but this should get you close:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbplotR)

Top10 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = xba.x, y = seq_along(xba.x))) +
  geom_mlb_headshots(aes(x = xba.x + 0.007, player_id = player_id), height = 0.15) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = xba.y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xba.y, yend = after_stat(y)))
```